# Font unit and ampersand in LESS with BEM syntax issues

Tags: html, css, less

I'm confused about ampersand behaviour in LESS compiler with BEM syntax and font unit

1. When using pxtoem to convert px to em with base font size in px is 12px (0.75em), but when converted to 11px, it is 0.917em.
2. About ampersand behaviour

Example:

```
<div class="search-form search-form--full">
    <p class="search-form__text">
</div>
```

As I know, `&` will just join (concatenate) the nested selector to the whole list of outer selectors or maybe same level, so:

```
search-form{
    &__text{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```

Will be complied to:

```
search-form search-form__text{
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

How can I join `--full` selector.

Thank in advance

Comment: I thin you should create two questions. But 1) See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510224/convert-px-to-em-in-less, 2) `search-form{&--full{}}` ??

Answer (score 0):

To get search-form--full, you have to do this :

```
.search-form{
    display:block;

    &__text{
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    &--full {
      color: #fff;
    }

 }
```

you will have :

```
.search-form {}
.search-form__text {}
.search-form--full {}
```

Answer (score 0):

About the PxToEm convertor, be careful to which element is the parent.

If we have a LESS or Sass Mixin to convert like .pxtoem();

E.g :

```
body { font-size: 16px }
span { .pxtoem(12) }
```

It's 12/16 = 0.75em

but if you do :

E.g :

```
p { font-size: 12px }
p span { .pxtoem(11) }
```

This time, it's 11/12 = 0.91em and not 11/16 (body font size);

Your mixin is certainly child divided by parent and not child divided by body

If you want this, use REM. Check this : http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem