# How to convert Px to Em using Less?

Tags: less

I got the same question: [Convert px to em in Less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510224/convert-px-to-em-in-less)

But these solutions doesn't work within `~"calc()"`.

I already tried to get help in #lesscss and ##lesscss but nobody knows.

Comment: What of "these solutions" have you've tried and how (showing some code never hurts)? The "basic arithmetic" (see [demo](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/VYEEpQ?editors=110)) and "custom JS function" methods actually can work with `calc` just fine. The "mixin" one won't unless you put `calc` into the mixin itself (but this basically spoils the very idea of it).

Comment: `~"+"` This already helped me. I didn't know about it. Thank you!